# db:migrate isn't working, despite successful sqlite3 install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

So I'm getting the following error whenever I run rake `db:migrate`

rake aborted!
no such file to load -- sqlite3

I did some googling and found that I may not have sqlite3 installed, so I `sudo port install sqlite3` and everything installs correctly, but when I go back to run `db:migrate` again, I get the same error.

I'm running Rails 2.3.8 on ruby 1.8.7 with sqlite3 3.7.2. Any ideas?

Comment: The port command you ran might have installed the sqlite binaries but not necessarily the sqlite3 ruby gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the sqlite3 gem? If you have, try uninstalling and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

try: `sudo gem install sqlite3`
and then:
`rake db:migrate`